# Dynamic Graph with Dijkstra with Neo4j

Tags: algorithm, graph, neo4j

Lets say I want to drive from Orange County to Brooklyn. And lets say I can go through Jerusalem. boom.

My graph will look like:

```
(Orange County) -> (Jerusalem) -> (Brooklyn)
    \---------------------------------/
```

Its all awesome and I can drive from Orange County to Jersusalem in 30 minutes. from Jerusalem to Brooklyn is 30 minutes too! If I'm starting to drive at noon, I'll get there in one hour!! 1 HOUR OF DRIVING. pretty rad.

But that's not the real life. in real life, I'll drive 30 minutes and then I may encounter heavy traffic that can hold me in my car for days! (well, something like that).
If I know I'm going to handle heavy traffic, I might not want to go to Jerusalem at all.

So lets imagine I have a "timeToArrive" property which is just an Array, splitted to quarters (`00:00 => arr[0], 00:15 => arr[1]`, etc.)
How can I use Dijkstra or any other tool to know which path should I take?

Should I build my own Algorithm? ("Dijkstra over time" or something..)

I'm talking about something like this: http://www.slideshare.net/neo4j/graph-connect-v5

Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you formulate a concrete example? Are the traffic scenarios given in terms of probabilities? Do you want to minimize the expected time of arrival? It'll be more understandable if you have a complete example question with all the figures.

Comment: @abhishek all the traffic data is known before the search is being made. I just want to give the relation the correct weight every time. So if the department is at 00:00 and graph is `(OC)-[30min]->(JERUSALEM)-[Xmin]->(BROOKLYN)` it will recalculate X for its weight at 00:30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some research I found out about the `PathExpander` interface that I can implement with a stateful implementation.

awesome.

Comment: https://github.com/Schniz/Neo4jGraphAvailabilityBlockerPlugin I wrote a plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think the you should use Dijkstra with a function g((u,v),t)=f(u,v) + h(t) while t is the current time which you are making the routing decition and (u,v) is the edge from u to v and f(u,v) is the approximated time from u to v without traffic t.
Next for h(t) you can do one of the following 
1. Create a db of approximated time from u to v at time t 
2. Use real time traffic updates 
3. Calculate some freaking geniuses heuristic for traffic calculation :)

Now use Dijkstra tough I would prefer using A* with time to travel heuristic over know graph without traffics

Comment: yeah, at the beginning I modified the `Dijkstra` implementation but then I found the `PathExpander` and I can check if `AStar` algorithm will be better.